# I want to add my variable in linux page cache

Tags: linux, radix-tree

I want to add my variable in linux page cache.
Page cache is managed by radix tree.

```
struct radix_tree_node {
unsigned long X[RADIX_TREE_MAP_SIZE];
}
```

I want to add my variable 'X' in radix-tree-node.
But, it doesn't work when fill 'X' of radix_tree_root.

There's an radix tree root named root. // struct radix_tree_root* root;
root has rnode, which is a pointer of radix_tree_node.

```
root->rnode->X[offset] = number;
```

It fails, and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it fail with some specific error? Could you update your question with it, too?

Comment: The error message was 'page dumped because: nonzero _count'... But, I didn't modify a count of page structure,so it is confusing.